# Android removing TitleBar for Activity causes ClassCastException. Why?

Tags: android, classcastexception

I'm getting a ClassCastException on the following line:

```
content = ((LinearLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content).getParent());
```

This is only when I set the theme of the Activity/App as `android:Theme.NoTitleBar`

Same problem with Fullscreen also.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(648): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView
```

Comment: if you want to get the root view use this `getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)` and your `content` variable probably is something else but `DecorView` class

Comment: Agree with @SergeyBenner. Your content is DecorView. But parent you are trying to get is PhoneWindow.

Comment: Thanx! It works fine now. And I changed findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1) which is the id of my parentView.